# Using StringTokenizer to re-create hashmap introduces extraneous characters

Tags: java, hashmap

I am new-ish to java, and I'm struggling to get my head around arrays, lists, string arrays, and strings.

Sorry this post is so long. I have read tutorials, articles, and books, but I'm obviously missing something.

My project contains a Gui app displaying values, which are obtained from a text file. The first pass retrieves the values from the file, by calling a second class, interrogating the text file, and returning them to the Gui app.

Once changed the Gui app sends the data out to the second app which is supposed to match the "keys" from the changed data, with the "keys" from the file. the changed data is in a KV hash-map, that is of course passed as String.valueOf the hash-map. I need to change the String that is passed into the second app back into the hash-map in order to "key" access the data rather than loop through the array until the match is found.

The problem I am having is that when the passed in string is converted to a hash-map, the value part of the hash-map contains the "," that separates the elements.

The sending hash-map is created from 11 lines like the following

```
cParmValueKv.put("NEWDSFDFT", String.valueOf(newDsfFileRbGrp.getSelection().getActionCommand()));
cParmValueKv.put("XPTPATH", xptoolsAppPathTf.getText());
```

The code to put it together and send it -

```
// Update the file
        cArgs = new String[11];
        cArgs[0] = "UPDATE";
        cArgs[1] = String.valueOf(cParmValueKv);

        // Go and get the data from the parms file
        XpgwParms.accessFile(cArgs);
```

My ide (IntelliJ) tells me the variable cArgs contains -

```
{RUNWEDDFT=Y, INFILEDFT=Y, WEDHLPDFT=Y, ELVUNTDFT=Y, SHWMATDFT=Y, USEWEDDFT=Y, ZIPPATH=C:\7Zip.exe, XPPATH=C:\Users\User\DeskTop\X-Plane\X-Plane Custom Scenery Path, WEDPATH=C:\WED.exe, XPTPATH=XPTOOLS App Path, NEWDSFDFT=Y}
```

The second app tells me the data received (cArgs[1]) contains -

```
{RUNWEDDFT=Y, INFILEDFT=Y, WEDHLPDFT=Y, ELVUNTDFT=Y, SHWMATDFT=Y, USEWEDDFT=Y, ZIPPATH=C:\7Zip.exe, XPPATH=C:\Users\User\DeskTop\X-Plane\X-Plane Custom Scenery Path, WEDPATH=C:\WED.exe, XPTPATH=XPTOOLS App Path, NEWDSFDFT=Y}
```

I run this code to re-create the hash-map created in the gui app -

```
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String[] keyValue = token.split("="); --> This line creates "Y,"
            if (keyValue.length == 2) {
                String key = keyValue[0];
                String value = keyValue[1]; 

                // Store the parts in the HashMap
                cKeyValueMap.put(key, value);
            }
        } // End of While
```

When the code ends I have the following data in cKeyValueMap -

```
"INFILEDFT" -> "Y,"
"WEDHLPDFT" -> "Y,"
"ELVUNTDFT" -> "Y,"
"SHWMATDFT" -> "Y,"
"USEWEDDFT" -> "Y,"
"ZIPPATH" -> "C:\7Zip.exe,"
"XPPATH" -> "C:\Users\User\DeskTop\X-Plane\X-Plane"
"WEDPATH" -> "C:\WED.exe,"
"{RUNWEDDFT" -> "Y,"
"XPTPATH" -> "XPTOOLS"
"NEWDSFDFT" -> "Y}"
```

Is this correct? Do I have to disregard the extraneous characters, or am I doing something wrong.

I have tried modifying the type of array used to pass the data, but I always need to come back to a kv pair.

Without some serious "fiddling" I cannot get a value of "N" or "Y" in place of the getActionCommand.

Comment: You're using a `StringTokenizer`? If so, avoid it - apart from being obsolete, it retains delimiters, which is probably why you're seeing commas. I'm not sure why you're not passing the `Map` itself rather than a string representation of it..?

Comment: If you need to tokenize the string (I'm not convinced that you should be passing anything other than the `Map` itself), then `String` itself has methods to do that, so maybe (for sample string `s`) something like: `Map<String, String>m = new HashMap<>();Arrays.stream(s.replaceAll("[{}]", "").split("\\s*,\\s*")).map(s ->s.split("=")).forEach(a ->m.put(a[0], a[1]));System.out.println(m);`

Comment: Hi,

If I code
cArgs[1] = cParmValueKv;
XpgwParms.accessFile(cArgs);

I get an error for the cArgs[1] line telling me to use String.valueOf(cParmsValueKv);

Your suggestion is greatfully received, but is there no easy way to get a hashmap out of one class and into another?

Comment: As there seems to be a consensus that I should not be using tokenizer, and passing the hashmap means the cArgs[1] is forced into a String, should I just abandon the hashmap idea, and just create a string than I can rebuild in the receiving class?

Comment: You probably don't need to do all this building in the first place. For a start what you have is a file full of key value properties so you can either use a `Properties` object or a JSON object. Then you can pass either of those objects to the method

Answer (score 0):

By default [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) uses white-space as a delimiter to separate tokens within a string. Use the [StringTokenizer Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) which allows you to use the delimiter you want for example:

**[Edited due to comment from OP]:**

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(myString, ",");
```

Now in the `while` loop, modify the code lines:

```
String key = keyValue[0];
String value = keyValue[1];
```

to this so to trim the keyValue[] array elements, like this:

```
String key = keyValue[0].trim();
String value = keyValue[1].trim();
```

**A Test:**

```
String strg = "{RUNWEDDFT=Y, INFILEDFT=Y, WEDHLPDFT=Y, ELVUNTDFT=Y, SHWMATDFT=Y, "
    + "USEWEDDFT=Y, ZIPPATH=C:\\7Zip.exe, "
    + "XPPATH=C:\\Users\\User\\DeskTop\\X-Plane\\X-Plane Custom Scenery Path, "
    + "WEDPATH=C:\\WED.exe, XPTPATH=XPTOOLS App Path, NEWDSFDFT=Y}".trim();
if (strg.startsWith("{") && strg.endsWith("}")) {
    strg = strg.substring(1, strg.length() - 1);
}
    
java.util.StringTokenizer tokenizer = new java.util.StringTokenizer(strg, ",");
    
// Header:
System.out.printf("%-12s %s %n", "Key", "Value");
System.out.println("-".repeat(18));

while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
    String[] keyValue = token.split("=");
    if (keyValue.length == 2) {
        String key = keyValue[0].trim();
        String value = keyValue[1].trim(); 
        System.out.printf("%-12s %s%n", key, value);
        // Store the parts in the HashMap
        //cKeyValueMap.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

**Console Output:**

```
Key          Value 
------------------
RUNWEDDFT    Y
INFILEDFT    Y
WEDHLPDFT    Y
ELVUNTDFT    Y
SHWMATDFT    Y
USEWEDDFT    Y
ZIPPATH      C:\7Zip.exe
XPPATH       C:\Users\User\DeskTop\X-Plane\X-Plane Custom Scenery Path
WEDPATH      C:\WED.exe
XPTPATH      XPTOOLS App Path
NEWDSFDFT    Y
```

---

**A Suggestion:**

Perhaps use java.util.Scanner class instead of StringTokenizer:

```
String strg = "{RUNWEDDFT=Y, INFILEDFT=Y, WEDHLPDFT=Y, ELVUNTDFT=Y, SHWMATDFT=Y, "
        + "USEWEDDFT=Y, ZIPPATH=C:\\7Zip.exe, "
        + "XPPATH=C:\\Users\\User\\DeskTop\\X-Plane\\X-Plane Custom Scenery Path, "
        + "WEDPATH=C:\\WED.exe, XPTPATH=XPTOOLS App Path, NEWDSFDFT=Y}";
if (strg.startsWith("{") && strg.endsWith("}")) {
    strg = strg.substring(1, strg.length() - 1);
}

// `Try With Resources` used here to auto-close Scanner
try (java.util.Scanner tokenizer = new java.util.Scanner(strg).useDelimiter(",\\s*")) {
    // Header:
    System.out.printf("%-12s %s %n", "Key", "Value");
    System.out.println("-".repeat(18));
        
    while (tokenizer.hasNext()) {
        String token = tokenizer.next();
        String[] keyValue = token.split("=");
        if (keyValue.length == 2) {
            String key = keyValue[0];
            String value = keyValue[1];
            System.out.printf("%-12s %s%n", key, value);
               
            // Store the parts in the HashMap
            //cKeyValueMap.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The argument `",\\s*)` passed to `.useDelimiter()` is a [Regular Expression](https://www.baeldung.com/regular-expressions-java) which basically means:
*use the comma (,) and none or possibly more white-spaces after the comma, as delimiter.*

**Console Output:**

```
Key          Value 
------------------
RUNWEDDFT    Y
INFILEDFT    Y
WEDHLPDFT    Y
ELVUNTDFT    Y
SHWMATDFT    Y
USEWEDDFT    Y
ZIPPATH      C:\7Zip.exe
XPPATH       C:\Users\User\DeskTop\X-Plane\X-Plane Custom Scenery Path
WEDPATH      C:\WED.exe
XPTPATH      XPTOOLS App Path
NEWDSFDFT    Y
```

Comment: I'm afraid your suggestion of using ", " causes the line 
if (keyValue.length == 2) {
to fail, and I end up with an empty map.

Comment: @Louise - It could be because the properties within the input string can contain white-spaces in the values. To solve this, see the edit in answer above.  Several corrections have been made. Again...better to use `java.util.Scanner` in my opinion.